# After adding gravity I can't run and walk faster

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make move script but it seems impossible to me because I stared at code for like an hour I even rewrote it but same problem. It appears that after I added gravity and groundcheck things, my character cant run or even walk at set speed (he is moving very slow). Can someone please help me with it please cuz' I'm lost

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //VARIABLES
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed;
 
    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Vector3 velocity;
 
    [SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
    [SerializeField] private float groundCheckDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity;
 
    //REFERENCES
    private CharacterController controller;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }
 
    private void Move()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckDistance, groundMask);
 
        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
 
        float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
 
        moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, moveZ);
 
        if(isGrounded)
        {
            if(moveDirection != Vector3.zero && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Walk();
            }
            else if(moveDirection != Vector3.zero && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(moveDirection == Vector3.zero)
            {
                Idle();
            }
 
            moveDirection *= moveSpeed;
        }
 
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
 
    private void Idle() 
    { 
    }
 
    private void Walk()
    {
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }
 
    private void Run()
    {
        moveSpeed = runSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem was with spawn area or call it how you want. If you'll move further the problem is no longer there.

Look at this video here: https://youtu.be/xfxgwmuPQsA